# How to Line-break text appearing Dynamically from database in a bootstrap label?

Tags: .net, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with asp.net. I have a bootstrap label whose contents are dynamically appearing from DB(sql server) on button click. A single cell of DB table contains multi-line text which has to be displayed in that label.

I have kept the data in database with break tags.
Now I am trying to replace break tag with Environment.NewLine as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    QuesHint.InnerText = datatable.Rows[i]["Ques_Description"].ToString();
    QuesHint.InnerText.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Here is my aspx :

```
<label id="QuesHint" runat="server" aria-multiline="True"></label>
```

But the output i get is : [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKBKc.gif) 
everything appears in 1 line.
How can i make this appear on next line.

PS : I have tried css properties like   `display: block; word-wrap: break-word;`
but nothing worked.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: if you want the text to appear on 2 lines why are you removing the break tags?

Comment: even without removing break tags it doesn't appear in next line. Infact the break tag also gets displayed in the label.

Comment: Please help me guys. I am really stuck on this for quite some time now.
Or if there is an alternative for this please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    QuesHint.InnerHtml = datatable.Rows[i]["Ques_Description"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Try with this one: `QuesHint.InnerText = QuesHint.InnerText.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: ohh god.. come on yaar ..! what I mean to say is `QuesHint.InnerText = datatable.Rows[i]["Ques_Description"].ToString();
   QuesHint.InnerText = QuesHint.InnerText.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: using QuesHint.InnerHtml actually worked for me.
Thanks for the help

Comment: ohh that's grate, then please mark this answer as a helpful :)